# Missing $ inserted when using \itemize and \approx

Tags: symbols

The line in question causing the issue is:

```
\item Blah blah blah \approx blah("blah") blah
```

I also tried `\left(` and `\right)`, but that didn't change anything.

No error is thrown when `\approx` is removed.

Comment: You need math mode: `$\approx$`.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks that worked. When is Latex automatically in math mode?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  LaTeX goes into math mode with `$`, or a `\[`, or some math environment such as `equation`, `align`, etc.  I don't think there is any mode where it goes into math mode without math mode specifically being invoked.